# Creating a DOT file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a DOT file from python and an error shows up saying :

```
[Errno 13 permission denied]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhZ4X.png)

This is the code i am using:

```
Credit_tree_file= open('c:\credit_tree.dot','w')
```

Can someone help me solve this please.

Comment: Please add code, So we can review it.Thanks

Comment: its in the image i attached but anyways i have added it to the original question

Comment: apparently you arent allowed to write to "c:\" directory

Comment: but i only have a single disk named c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a normal user, you are usually not allowed (and, you should not be allowed) to write into the root directory of your disk drive. However, you of course have access to other locations like your own home directory or the temp directory. You can try to create the file in your temp directory, for example like

```
import tempfile
import os

tmpdir = tempfile.gettempdir()
Credit_tree_file = open(os.path.join(tmpdir, 'credit_tree.dot'),'w')
...
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, So does that mean i have to follow these codes everytime i have to do this particular task